# Use zoom as filter in tableau

Tags: filter, zoom

Ao ver alguns tutoriais, verifiquei que existe a possibilidade de utilizar action clicks para alterar a informação que é apresentada no dashboard, de acordo com a selecção feita.
A informação genérica, sem selecções é apresentada no dashboard, sendo que após a selecção, os dados são alterados em confirmidade (imagem apresentada de seguida)

[image: Dashboard (geral à esquerda e com selecção à direita)]

O meu objectivo é de obter a mesmo informação mas fazendo apenas zoom sem ser necessário fazer selecções.

Alguém sabe?

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow **em Português**. Por favor traduza sua pergunta.